# Does adding on to a statement mean you agree with it?

Tags: comprehension

If Person A says "Never trust a used car salesman or a politician" and Person B says "Or a lawyer" is it implied that person B agrees with Person A? Is there a word or phrase for this?

Comment: Did you really mean to write **poicitian** in B's answer, or is it a typo? Either way, actually, B's answer sounds strange. If B mentioned some occupation clearly distinct from a used car salesman and a politician, then you could indeed conclude B thinks that people in all three occupations are untrustworthy. One exception is if the occupation that B mentions has something to do with A, in which case B's comment is probably ironic and it implies that it is A who shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: @linguisticturn 
Sorry. Thanks for that. I fixed it. I wrote it then proofread it and saw what I wanted to see.

Comment: OK, so now, unless A is a lawyer himself, we can probably assume B agrees that used car salesmen and politicians are untrustworthy. At the very least, we can assume that B doesn't strongly disagree with A.

Comment: A: 'He might very well return the money he borrowed.' B: 'Yes, and pigs might one day fly.' B has added to A's statement but quite clearly does not agree with it. The premise of the Question is not infallible.

Answer (score 2):

There's an implication of agreement but person B has not directly agreed. Now if person A were a lawyer, person B would be saying that person A is not to be trusted. My view is that this is a way of suggesting agreement without actually agreeing.